# Form with nested set dropdown

Tags: joomla-3.x, form, joomla3.8, dropdown

I have to write front-end form in my component with dropdown list of categories and subcategories. Categories and subcategories amount should be unlimited. Should I use a nested sets model to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you implement your own categories functionality you can use anything that suits you.

However you can take advantage of Joomla's built-in categories system for your component.

Have a read here:
[**Developing an MVC Component/Adding categories**](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_categories)

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of this page it shows you how to do something similar. https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type

It sounds like you may wish to do an override of the already existing categories form field.

https://docs.joomla.org/Category_form_field_type

Here's a full list

https://docs.joomla.org/Standard_form_field_types